# check if a value from object has a character

Tags: python, django

Im testing how to check if a string has a character " or + and in this case i dont create a backlink

for example this 2 samples are wrong

> "this is a category linked"

<< this create a error
and this
`

> "+ tutorial"

i need tutorial or This is a category linked without the `<a ahref>` atributes

So i want check if a string contains " or + i try with 
on the template html i try

```
          {% if topic.category == '"' %}<a href="topic.slug"> {{topic.category}}</a>{%endif%}
```

but this dont work, maybe i need check the string before pass to the template or is other bad aproach?

Answer (score 2):

Does `in` operator supports your need?

For example:

`>>> '+' in '+ tutorial'
True`